# Getting AmazonDynamoDBException: User: arn:aws:iam:USER is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:ListTables

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, configuration, amazon-dynamodb

I am struggling with an AmazonDynamoDBException while DynamoDB configuration and connection attempt.
Configuration code looks like:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class AWSDynamoDBConfig {

    private final String accessKey;
    private final String secretKey;
    private final String roleArn;

    public AWSDynamoDBConfig() throws IOException {
        Properties properties = readProperties("common", "aws.properties");
        accessKey = properties.getProperty("aws.accessKey");
        secretKey = properties.getProperty("aws.secretKey");
        roleArn = properties.getProperty("aws.roleArn");
    }

    public AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest() {
        return new AssumeRoleRequest().withRoleArn(roleArn);
    }

    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
                .withCredentials(amazonAWSCredentialProvider())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AWSCredentials amazonAWSCredential() {
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapperConfig dynamoDBMapperConfig() {
        return DynamoDBMapperConfig.DEFAULT;
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper(AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB, DynamoDBMapperConfig config) {
        return new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB, config);
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamoDB dynamoDB() {
        return new DynamoDB(amazonDynamoDB());
    }

    public AWSCredentialsProvider amazonAWSCredentialProvider() {
        return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(amazonAWSCredential());
    }

}
```

which produce an error while method call `listTables`

```
public void listMyTables() {
        TableCollection<ListTablesResult> tables = awsDynamoDBConfig.dynamoDB().listTables();
        Iterator<Table> iterator = tables.iterator();

        log.info("Listing tables from DynamoDB instance");
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Table table = iterator.next();
            log.info("Table name: " + table.getTableName());
        }
    }
```

> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: User: arn:aws:iam::number:user/machine-USER is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:ListTables on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:number:table/* (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: ID-Number)

As far as I know, I am missing `roleArn` in the AmazonDynamoDB object so that's why I want to add it.
So far I have found a topic [click](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/delegating-api-access-to-aws-services-using-iam-roles/) but above solution use deprecated Object `AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient` and after all, I would use the new Object `AmazonDynamoDB` but I did not find out how to make it real.
I will be grateful for the suggestions on how to add missing `arnRole` to the `AmazonDynamoDB` object to finish the configuration step and establish the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either setup an IAM policy or an inline policy on a Role that is running this code. Not sure if it's a lambda or in a container, or something else, either way, your policy would need to look something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:ListTables"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:number:table/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Anyway, I need to know how to pass `arnRole` to the AmazonDynamoDB object on Java side, not how to configure IAM via AWS or I got something wrong.

Comment: You're not going to pass it, the role is assigned to the Security credentials e.g. the accessKey and secretKey, then when you try and list tables, DynamoDB checks with IAM to see if that user has the right permissions.